# Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('AED')->getSymbol() return NULL in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

I have created multi currency website in Magento 1.9. On product page I'm trying to get current currency symbol using below code :

```
$symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

This code is working for all currency except `AED`. For `AED` currency above code return `NULL`.

Why this is happening? 
How to resolve it?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get `string '$' (length=1)`. I'd check `Config -> Currency Setup` and `System -> Manage Currency -> Symbols`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Magento does not have Symbols for some of the currencies. You need to add symbols for these currencies manually.

To add currency symbol, Go to `System > Manage Currencies > Symbol`

- Uncheck "use standard" for your currency (AED (United Arab Emirates Dirham))
- Add symbol you want to add for AED
- Click on Save Currency Symbols

PS: There are some more currencies which does not have default symbols available in Magento. e.g. SEK, SDG, GQE

**EDIT**

I have debug default Magento Currency display functionality and I found below.
When Magento displays product price, It calls function

`Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::formatTxt($price, $options = array())`

This function then returns below

```
return Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
```

Here `toCurrency` function is called from **lib/Zend/Currency.php**

`Zend_Currency::toCurrency($value = null, array $options = array())`

For `AED` currency it sends one parameter in `$options['display']` with value `3` If you `var_dump($options)` in this function you will get all data like below.

```
array (size=12)
  'precision' => int 2
  'position' => int 8
  'script' => null
  'format' => null
  'display' => int 3
  'name' => string 'United Arab Emirates Dirham' (length=27)
  'currency' => string 'AED' (length=3)
  'symbol' => null
  'locale' => string 'en_US' (length=5)
  'value' => int 0
  'service' => null
  'tag' => string 'Zend_Locale' (length=11)
```

In the same function there is below code.

```
switch($options['display']) {
    case self::USE_SYMBOL:
        $sign = $this->_extractPattern($options['symbol'], $original);
        break;

    case self::USE_SHORTNAME:
        $sign = $options['currency'];
        break;

    case self::USE_NAME:
        $sign = $options['name'];
        break;

    default:
        $sign = '';
        $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        break;
}
```

This code defines what symbol, string to append for price. For `AED` it uses `USE_SHORTNAME`, and thus it adds currency short name and not symbol.

That is the reason you see Currency symbol (which is actually currency short name) in price and not in your code

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

As you can see in `var_dump` data the symbol value for AED is `null`

Comment: But on other places it is showing `AED` currency symbol, and when I try to get it returns me `NULL`.

Comment: On which places you can see currency symbol ?

Comment: On cart page, checkout page, everywhere with price, where price is coming from magento functions.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari, I added more description. Please review.